# Getting Blank table after performing valid query in spark sql

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new in spark. i am facing a weird problem  after submitting valid query inside  pyspark
my sql query is

```
spark.sql("
SELECT ID
     , ENTITYID
     , BldgID
     , LeaseID
     , SuiteID
     , TxnDate
     , IncomeCat
     , SourceCode
     , Period
     , Dept
     , ActualProjected
     , ((TChargeAmt1*TDays1)/(TTotalDays)+(TChargeAmt2*TDays2)/(TTotalDays)) as ChargeAmt 
     , OpenAmt
     , Invoice
     , CurrencyCode
     , GLClosedStatus
     , GLPostedStatus
     , PaidStatus
     , Frequency
     , RetroPD
     , FCWorkBook
     , FCLeaseNo
     , FCSuitID
     , TxnDateInt 
  FROM Fact_CMCharges f  
  JOIN TT  
    ON tt.TID = f.ID 
 WHERE tt.TID <> NULL
").show()
```

my result after this
[image]

which is fine up to this then  i have save this dataframe in registerTempTable

```
spark.sql(" select ID, ENTITYID,BldgID,LeaseID,SuiteID,TxnDate,IncomeCat,SourceCode,Period,Dept,ActualProjected,((TChargeAmt1*TDays1)/(TTotalDays)+(TChargeAmt2*TDays2)/(TTotalDays)) as ChargeAmt ,OpenAmt,Invoice,CurrencyCode,GLClosedStatus,GLPostedStatus,PaidStatus,Frequency,RetroPD,FCWorkBook,FCLeaseNo,FCSuitID,TxnDateInt from Fact_CMCharges f FULL JOIN  TT  on TID=f.ID where TID<>null ").registerTempTable('testwithTID')
```

and my table data are showing same as my dataframe field value
now for testing purpose i have test some query on it like

```
spark.sql("select ID,ChargeAmt from testwithTID").show()
```

and my result is

[image]

which is fine as well. but when i perform simple where query on table like

```
spark.sql("select ID,ChargeAmt from testwithTID where ID=2740189134848").show()
```

i am getting this

[image]

it seems very weird and new to me. there is no missing or incompatible  fields in table but getting blank value is really unexpected. kindly help me about this scenario why it is happening and what will be possible solution . I am using pyspark 2.0 
Thanks in Advance
Kalyan

Comment: What type is `ID`? String? If yes, you might need to alter the query to `select ID,ChargeAmt from testwithTID where ID='2740189134848'`.

Comment: Note that nothing is neither equal nor not equal to null. Not even null! The comparison for null is 'IS NULL' or 'IS NOT NULL'

Comment: um @LImuBei  ID is BIGINT value i have tried string format too but it remain unchanged